# Separating views, command presentation (Text, Icon) and command logic (Execute, CanExecute)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, routed-commands

If TL;DR: see the last paragraph.

Pure WPF "suggests" putting presentation (controls, text, icons) into views and command logic (Execute, CanExecute methods) into code-behind. Besides putting logic both into views (`CommandBindings`) and code-behind being a frowned upon practice, it doesn't help at all with **XAML duplication**: text, icons, large icons, hints, and numerous other properties have to be **duplicated every time** a command is used: for main menu, for context menu, for toolbar button, for ribbon button and other controls.

Looks like the first problem (truly separating views and logic) is solved by `DelegateCommand`, `RelayCommand` and approaches like that. Command logic is moved into ViewModels (or Controllers in case of MVVMC), code-behind is clean, no `CommandBindings` and other nonsense in views.

However, I can't find a commonly accepted solution to the presentation duplication problem. I want to separate **command presentation** (text, icons) and **command logic** (`Execute`, `CanExecute` methods). All code I could find either puts presentation into code (by creating a `RoutedCommand` with additional properties like `Label` and `Icon`), or puts code into presentation (that is, handlers into views and code-behind). I don't like either. I think presentation should be completely in XAML, and code should be completely in CS (either in ViewModel or Controller).

**Question:** how to separate views (XAML with controls which reference commands), presentation of commands (labels, icons etc. for every command) and logic of commands (C# code for `Execute`, `CanExecute` etc. in ViewModels or Controllers)?

Comment: Two close votes already? And zero comments? Is the question unasnwerable or did I miss something? If you vote to close, leave a comment at least, please. I can't learn if you don't tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Read the "non constructive" description on the FAQ - "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". By that same token, Stack Overflow is not a good place to ask "how should I build my software?" questions.

Comment: @JeanHominal The way I see it, I haven't asked how to build MY software, I've asked about a problem I think is *very common*, considering how much code I've seen where this problem isn't solved, even in Microsoft's code. And judging by votes (5 +1 votes from 20 views), I'm not the only one who wants to find a solution.

Comment: I really should have kept only the first sentence of my previous comment. I meant that it is likely that any answer will result in debate. (A lot of "patterns" questions result in that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in solution to this problem, your're going to have to roll-up your sleeves and create the required structure yourself.

In a recent project I worked on, I did exactly this. I created a concept called an 'action' which supplements the WPF `ICommand` with other visual properties. It was something like this ...

```
interface IAction
{
  ICommand Command { get; }
  string DisplayText { get; }
  string ToolTipText{ get; }
  URI Icon { get; }
}
```

The application contained a collection of `Action` instances. These could then be bound to menus, toolbars etc ... allowing the same `Action` instance to be re-used with various different presentation styles. It is all fairly straightforward MVVM stuff!